# HTML Javascript changing content of table cell

Tags: javascript

I want to change the content of the cell in the table by pressing the button, without using input textbox. 
What should I use to do it?
Thanks!

Here's my code:

`

```
var images = new Array();
var i=0;

images[0] ="1.jpg";
images[1] ="2.jpg";
images[2] ="3.jpg";
images[3] ="4.jpg";

names = ["New York", "Nagasaki", "Nottingham", "Netherlands"]

function next(){
    if(i>=images.length){
        i=0;
        document.getElementById('names').value=names[i];
        document.getElementById('img').src=images[i];   
        i++;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('img').src=images[i];
        document.getElementById('names').value=names[i];
        i++;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body><center>
<h3>LabExercise3</h3>
<h2>By <i><b><u>Nurbek Zhapar</u></b></i></h2></center>
<form>
<h1>Around the World</h1><br/>
<hr/>
<br/>
    <table align="center">
        <tr><td><input type="text" value="" id="names" readonly="readonly"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><p style="text-align:center;">
            <img src="1.jpg" alt=""  id="img"/>
            </p></td></tr></table>

<table align="center">
  <tr>
       <td><input type="button" value=" Next " onclick="next()" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>        
</form>`
```

I want to replace input textbox that I used here to display Country names by something else, or show Country names in other way. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you effectively, we would need a lot more information. What does your table look like (post your markup)? Where is the button? What should the contents change to?

Comment: What do you mean by "without using the textbox"? What you posted works fine with just pressing the button.

Comment: I just want to change text in the cell of the table by pressing the button each time. Here it changes inside the textbox. But I shouldn't use textbox, just the cell.

Comment: Well, you could remove the `<input ...>` element, and remove all `document.getElementById('names')` lines as well. You also don't need the `names` array anymore. Basically just remove everything related to the textbox.

Comment: If I remove all of the things that you mentioned Web page will have only changing Images. But I also need Names of the images to change. And they should change inside the cell, not inside the textbox. I just want to get rid of the textbox. But still have changing names in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `<span id="name"></span>` inside the table cell, and update `document.getElementById("name").textContent` instead of the textbox.

You also ought to think about your HTML and JavaScript. There are quite a few things you're using that are deprecated.

See http://jsfiddle.net/3sEYq/.

Comment: Using span worked well for me, although in my case textContent wasn't cooperating. I had to use innerText instead. Great blog post on the subject here: [perfectionkills.com](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/)